# ExtJS populate store from multiple proxy sources

Tags: javascript, database, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a distributed database system and I want my EXTJS app to request data from multiple sources and put it into a single store.  Is there a way to define multiple proxy urls for a single store?  Is the best way to accomplish this to make multiple stores and merge them before the data is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion best way to aggregate data from multiple sources is aggregate it on your backend and return with help one endpoint.

Extjs does not support multiple proxy. But you can create as many stores as you have sources, and collect all data in one memory store. But in this case you lose many features, where help you work with remote proxy store

Answer (score 0):

Not using a single proxy out of the box, you could create a custom proxy, but that would overcomplicate things:

There are a few ways to skin this cat also (assuming flat store / not treestore)

1) Multiple stores loading and then populating a central store grabbing records with getData() to grab records from the store, then use 'beforeload' event to manually trigger a load() on the distributed stores.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-getData

2) Using Ajax requests to get data then append into a large array then using loadData() on a memory store to populate the store.

I'm sure there's others also, and depends how 'large' the store is... if it's massive it might just be simpler to sync all records to one database and then present them in store.